# How to handle "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'"

Tags: angular

I'm having a condition where the date-time stamp is sometimes `null`. In those cases my date pipe is failing.

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf="studentInfo?.classRoom?.id;">
  {{getDateObject(studentInfo?.classRoom?.dob) | date: sharedModule.getDateTimeFormat() :
              sharedModule.getDateTimeZoneDefault(getDateObject(studentInfo?.classRoom?.dob))}}
</div>
```

This runs good untill the `dateString` in below function is passed `null`.

**TS:**

```
getDateObject(dateString) {
  return moment(dateString).toDate();
}
```

That's when it starts logging:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Can someone please help me with this. Passing `null` value is still fine. But the UI should handle this Pipe issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a if condition to handle this, that's all, so that null is not passed to the date pipe!

```
<div *ngIf="studentInfo?.classRoom?.id;">
  {{studentInfo?.classRoom?.dob ? 
             getDateObject(studentInfo?.classRoom?.dob) | date: sharedModule.getDateTimeFormat() :
              sharedModule.getDateTimeZoneDefault(getDateObject(studentInfo?.classRoom?.dob))
 : ''}}
</div>
```